# Sublevel set estimates on Complex

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it known?

If $f:D→\mathbb{C}$  is holomorphic function in $D$ , where $D$ is compact, connected (and convex, if necessary) set, and 
\begin{align}
|f^{(k)}| \ge 1 \ \ \text{ on  } \  D
\end{align}
holds then
\begin{align}
 |\{z \in D : |f|\le \alpha\}| ≤ C\alpha^{2/k}
\end{align}
(Of course, Real version is well-known.)